# How to make a step by step display animation in openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation

How to make a step by step display animation in openGL??

I'M doing a reprap printer project to read a GCode file and interpret it into graphic. 
now i have difficulty make a step by step animation of drawing the whole object.
i need to draw many short lines to make up a whole object.
for example:

```
|-----|
|     |
|     |
|-----|
```

the square is made up of many short lines, and each line is generated by code like:

```
glPushMatrix();
.....
for(int i=0; i< instruction[i].size(),i++)
{  ....
   glBegin(GL_LINES);
     glVertex3f(oldx, oldy, oldz);
     glVertex3f(x, y, z);
   glEnd();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

now i want to make a step animation to display how this square is made. I tried to refresh the screen each time a new line is drawn, but it doesn't work, the whole square just come out at once. anyone know how to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical OpenGL implementations will queue up large number of calls to batch them together into bursts of activity to make optimal use of available communication bandwidth and GPU time resources.

What you want to do is basically the opposite of double buffered rendering, i.e. rendering where each drawing step is immediately visible. One way to do this is by rendering to a single buffered window and call `glFinish()` after each step. Major drawback: It's likely to not work well on modern systems, which use compositing window managers and similar.

Another approach, which I recommend, is using a separate buffer for incremental drawing, and constantly refreshing the main framebuffer from this one. The key subjects are *Frame Buffer Object* and *Render To Texture*.

First you create a FBO (tons of tutorials out there and as answers on StackOverflow). A FBO is basically an abstraction to which you can connect target buffers, like textures or renderbuffers, and which can be bound as the destination of drawing calls.

So how to solve your problem with them? First you should not do the animation by delaying a drawing loop. This has several reasons, but the main issue is, that you loose program interactivity by this. Instead you maintain a (global) counter at which step in your animation you are. Let's call it `step`:

```
int step = 0;
```

Then in your drawing function you have to phases: 1) Texture update 2) Screen refresh

Phase one consists of binding your framebuffer object as render target. For this to work the target texture must be unbound

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, animFBO);
glViewport(0, 0, fbo.width, fbo.height);
set_animFBO_projection();
```

the trick now is, that you clear the animFBO only once, namely after creation, and then never again. Now you draw your lines according to the animation step

```
draw_lines_for_step(step);
```

and increment the step counter (could do this as a compound statement, but this is more explicit)

```
step++;
```

After updating the animation FBO it's time to update the screen. First unbind the animFBO

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

We're now on the main, on-screen framebuffer

```
glViewport(0, 0, window.width, window.height);
set_window_projection(); //most likely a glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1);
```

Now bind the FBO attached texture and draw it to a full viewport quad

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, animFBOTexture);
draw_full_viewport_textured_quad();
```

Finally do the buffer swap to show the animation step iteration

```
SwapBuffers();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the SwapBuffer method called after each draw call.
Be sure you don't screw the matrix stack and you'll probably need something to "pause" the rendering like a breakpoint.

Comment: The swap buffer call will may very likely corrupt the contents of the back buffer, so drawing continuation won't work.

Comment: the SwapBuffer didn't work, i don't know if that's because the coordinates file is too large or some other reason. the program was into forever running mood and nothing display on the screen....but thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the Lines to appear one after another and you dont have to be nit-picking about efficiency or good programming style try something like:

(in your drawing routine)

> `if (timer > 100)`
>   `{`
>
> `//draw the next line`
>
> `timer = 0;`
>
> `}`
>
> `else`
>
> `timer++;`
>
> `//draw all the other lines (you have to remember wich one already appeared)`
>
> `//for example using a boolean array "lineDrawn[10]"`

The timer is an integer that tells you, how often you have drawn the scene. If you make it larger, stuff happens more slowly on the screen when you run your program.

Of course this only works if you have a draw routine. If not, I strongly suggest using one.

->plenty tutorials pretty everywhere, e.g.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/

Goor luck to you!

PS: I think you have done nearly the same, but without a timer. thats why everything was drawn so fast that you thought it appeared all at the same time.